# Why is there a popup alert for iOS DeepView attempting to find the URI

Tags: branch.io

For a user who clicks on a Branch link and who has not installed my app, a popup alert displays saying it can't find the iOS URI I specified in the
iOS URI Scheme.

The URI scheme is only for users who have already downloaded the app and the popup alert is bizarre (nobody understands what `my-app-uri` is nor would anyones domain name match their URI as in `my-app-uri.com`).

The interim solution is to delete the URI option so that it only redirects to the App Store. Unfortunately this gets rid of the DeepView as well.

How do I either:

- A. Obtain a DeepView but get rid of the popup
- B. Ignore the DeepView completely and just go to App Store *AND* still retain ability for a user to try the URI.

[image: ios screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

What you are experiencing is our URI Scheme Deep Link Mode. Currently it is set to Intelligent Mode, which will only try to force a URI scheme app opening, if we have seen the specific device open your application recently. If we have seen the given device open your application recently - we will assume that the application is installed on the device. Branch will then try to forcefully open the application via the URI scheme, if Universal Linking fails.
Unfortunately, if the application is not installed anymore, iOS displays an error message.

This error is very common during testing, as you are constantly reinstalling the application.
Regular users, as our research has shown, almost never encounter this issue, however, the application is opened at a higher rate than without it.

You could disable the URI Scheme Deep Link Mode in your Link Settings page, if you would like your users to never run into this issue, however, it will hurt your app open rate.

I hope this helps!